# sweetalert not waiting in async methods with vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, sweetalert2

I am trying to use SweetAlert2 with Vue3 (composition API). With the following code, the alert doesn't wait for its button to be clicked:

```
onBeforeMount(async() => {
  Swal.fire('test message');
  initialiseArrays();
  await getRides();
});
```

If I remove `async`,

```
onBeforeMount(() => {
  Swal.fire('test message');
  initialiseArrays();
  //await getRides();
});
```

***or*** add `async` to the 'Swal' call, it works as expected:

```
onBeforeMount(async() => {
  async Swal.fire('test message');
  initialiseArrays();
  await getRides();
});
```

The function `getRides` waits for data from the server and populates some lists. I don't actually need to use `Swal` in  `onBeforeMount()`, but it will be used deeper inside `getRides`, where again it does not work unless I add `await` to every use of `Swal`. But that means making virtually every function of my code `async` - which cannot be right!

I have tried moving part of the `getRides` code into the `onMounted` hook, but  that is called before the data is fully loaded, so leads to complications. I will however progress with this method unless there is no other solution.

Comment: [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) can only wait if `getRides()` returns a Promise.  Does it?  Show the code for this function

Comment: No, it doesn't - but in fact it doesn't need `await` either, that's a red herring, sorry. It does however have successive calls to `Swal` which is the problem - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085851/sweetalert2-multiple-swal-at-the-same-function

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware (or had forgotten) that `Swal` is non-blocking, so just calling a second will immediatly destroy the first, unless either

- each call has `await`, which then means that any function using it must be declared `async`, (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085851/sweetalert2-multiple-swal-at-the-same-function) for a complete answer) or
- call the subsequent alert in a callback of the first - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980981/sweetalert-blocking-like-normal-prompt) for lots more details - this will require some code restructuring on my part, since there are multiple uses deep in my `getRides` function.